# What's the difference in TWIG between using the attribute() function and using brackets

Tags: twig

I'm trying to understand twigs attribute() function, because it seems to me that this

```
attribute(object, parameter)
```

and this

```
object[ parameter ]
```

Would do the same thing. They return the value of that parameter in the object. I realize that brackets can also be used to get a value from an array with an index, but if the parameter is a string it seems to get the value from the parameter just as well. What else does attribute() do that Im missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `attribute` function can also be used to call methods of objects and enables you to pass arguments towards it

```
{{ attribute(object, method, arguments) }}
```